# More then one dynamic table with dynamic column swift 4

Tags: swift, dynamically-generated

**table: [{

Id,

Name,

Type,

row[{

Id,

Name

}],

column[{

Id,

Name

}]

}]**

[blog.adgager.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/mobile_surveys.jpeg](https://blog.adgager.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/mobile_surveys.jpeg)

( a simple piece of representation )

I need to add more than one table to a controller. The data will come as json. the image will be sorted into View controller.

How should i do it?
I'm using swift 4 programmatically tableview

How to dynamically create more than one tableview in a single ControllerView.

The table must have more than one column. Table rows to be filled by table type.
If the row type is checkbox, the label in the first column will be the checkbox in all other columns.

how can I do it?

Thanks from now.

Comment: TableView cannot have more than 1 column. Use collectionView instead.

Comment: can I add a dynamically collectionview with a changeable column?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to take one tableview with multiple section and rows.Not sure how your UX looks like. but when we have a concept of numberOfSection and NumberOf Rows where each section can separated by header (Grouped tableview) then don't know why do we need multiple tableview in one ViewController.

Comment: my UX partition will be partition. her satırda sorular ya da önermeler olacak. 
The problem here is that I need to show this list on one page.
 Here is an example of the picture in the link.
There is only one section here.
https://blog.adgager.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/mobile_surveys.jpeg

Comment: I wish you'd put that image in the initial question!  That only needs one tableView cell with one section and a custom table cell and header.

Comment: @lifeCode your UX is pretty simple, as flanker said one tableview with Custom cell is enough, put the servey part and all as tableview header or section header based on your scrolling requirement.

Comment: I'm sorry. There may be n pieces from this table. and the line column may come from a variable.the count of rows can be N. the count of columns may be N.I'll try the code you shared above.

Comment: If count of column is N then how would you fit that in screen, in that case it should be horizontal scrolling(for dynamic column). better approach is tableview cell should contain collectionView

Comment: Yes. I thought to scrape with stackview on the outside. Can I handle the problem if I add a collectionview to it?

Comment: you can do with stackView, actually that's a better solution. yes with collectionView you can achieve your use case

Answer (score 0):

Creating more than one tableview is relatively straightfoward. I assume the same applies for CollectionView, which is what you'll need if you want true multi-column rather than mukti-component tableView cells, although I've never tried.

Simply put you need to instantiate two tableviews and just add them as subViews.  The interesting bit comes with handling delegate functions.  You have two choices:

1. use two different classes as the delegates, one for each.  This is often easier to understand, but does involve duplication of a lot of boiler plate code.
2. use 1 class for both delegates (could even be the view controller but it risks massive view controller syndrome) and test in each method which tableview it applies too.

The first of those is pretty obvious, so below is a high-level example of the second.

```
class MyCustomCell: UITableViewCell {
  static let cellID = "CustomCellID"
  // set up custom tableViewCell as required
}

class MyVC: UIViewController {
  var table1 = UITableView()
  var table2 = UITableView()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad
    table1.delegate = self
    table1.datasource = self
    table2.delegate = self
    table2.datasource = self
    view.addSubview(table1)
    view.addSubview(table2)
    tableView.register(MyCustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: MyCustomCell.cellID)
    tableView.register(MyCustomCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: MyCustomCell.cellID)
    //some AutoLayout code to layout the tables in the view
  }
}

extension MyVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
     if tableView === table1 {
        //return appropriate value for section in table 1
     } else {
       //return appropriate value for section in table 1
     }
  }

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if tableView === table1 {
      //create and return cell for table 1
    } else {
      //create and return cell for table 2
    }
  }
}
```

Obviously this is only the outline and will require the actual implementation code and the other necessary tableView functions.  Note the use of `===` to check the tableViews.  This checks that they are exactly the same object rather than just equivalent objects.

Where you need to have the same for both tables (eg. you want them to use the same tableViewCell), then you can possibly do away without checks.

Having written all that, unless at least one of the tables is showing a static number of rows and can have scrolling disabled, I'd say it's likely to look awful on an iPhone, and in most cases not much better on an iPad!

Comment: Given the image you added as a comment to the other answer, that indicates you don't want need what you originally asked for, then this probably isn't relevant, but I'll leave it here in case anyone else comes upon it through searching for more than one dynamic tableview!